# iv-user header value is null when it reaches to backend API from Kong

Tags: kong

Even though I am passing iv-user header and its value on my request while accessing an API from Kong when it reaches to the backend API I am noticing that the iv-user value is (null).
Tried with file logs to check back on kong request headers noticed that the iv-user value is proper in the file logs.

Am I missing something here?why the iv-user header value is (null) when it reached the backend API.

Comment: Can you do a tcpdump to check what is going to the backend ?

Comment: Are you sure the header is removed ?
What is your configuration ?
Can you share a minimal conf to reproduce the error ?

Comment: Thank you Orel. I am running kong(2.2.0) on https mode so not found any clue from the tcpdumps. Yes iv-user:(null) when it reached backend API. Simple the setup is, I published an API to Kong(the api is running on http protocol) and when I am trying to access this API through Kong I am setting an header called "iv-user:admin" and then I am checking back this iv-user value in my backend API which is coming as null. But, noticed that on the kong request headers this value seems to proper "iv-user:admin".

Comment: What about setting an http server to check what kong is sending ?
Perhaps the pblm is in you backend part

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out the root cause. The problem was neither with Kong nor with the backend API. There is a proxy layer in between these two. This proxy was setting the iv-user header value to null. This proxy is the one which sets the iv-user value usually. As because we are not authenticating through proxy and its just a pass through to Kong hence this proxy is nullifying this value.